# how to find a vector?

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the inner product

$\left<(a_1, a_2),(b_1, b_2)\right> = 2a_1b_1 − a_1b_2 − a_2b_1 + 5a_2b_2$ on $R^2$

Write down a vector which is orthogonal to$ (1, 0)$ and has norm $1.$

My solution : i convert them into matrix

$A=  \begin{bmatrix} 2&-1\\-1&5\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}2\\-1\end{bmatrix}$

Now  i don't know how to find a vectors which is orthogonal to$ (1, 0)$ and has norm $1.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply write two equations for both conditions and then solve the system. 
They would be $2b_1-b_2=0$ and $2b_1^2-2b_1b_2+5b_2^2=1$.

Comment: ,@Logic,,,,that mean answer will  be  (2,-2) ,and (-2,5)

Comment: $b_2=2b_1$ has to be true, so no.

Comment: my question is  that  if $b_2 = 2b_1$  then  it  will  be $2a_1b_1 − a_12b_1 − a_2b_1 + 5a_22b_1$.....as  im not getting

Comment: One condition is $\langle (1,0),(b_1,b_2)\rangle=0$ and another is $\langle (b_1,b_1),(b_1,b_2)\rangle=1$. They lead to the equations I have wrote above.

Comment: You have to insert $b_2=2b_1$ into the $2b_1^2-2b_1b_2+5b_2^2=1$ and then solve it.

Comment: \begin{bmatrix} 2&-2\\-2&5\end{bmatrix}  now  $(2,-2)$ and $(-2,5)$  are required  vector,,,,Is its correct or not ?

Comment: I don't see what is a matrix good for in this case.

Comment: But $(2,-2)$ and $(-2,5)$ are obviously not the correct answer.

Comment: what  is the correct answer ?? @ Logic

Comment: $\pm (1/\sqrt{18},2\sqrt{18})$

Comment: PLiz  elaborate its   @Logic...Im not getting  how  ur  answer come...$(1 / \sqrt 18,2\sqrt 18)$???

Comment: i got its   thanks   a lots @logic,,,,,,